# Символы в окне вывода и в описании ошибок Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019

В окне вывода и описании ошибки : "ёё√ыър эр эхЁрчЁх°хээ√щ тэх°эшщ ёшьтюы "void __cde ...."

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Весёлый баг. Нужно или 1)заявить в микрософт и ждать патча. 2) Написать "взламывающий" плагин, найти окно "output" в среде, разобраться как откопать там текст, и перекодировать текст в окне вывода. 3) попробовать процесс VS запустить из под английской локали.

Comment: Может это проблема в кодировке? Посмотрите в настройках системы. Ну или как это уже выше написали, это может быть баг)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

изменил язык в студии на английский